# Not able to move file into folder in php

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload, mysqli

I am unable to move file into desired folder. I want to save image into uploaded folder. In mysql i have it in blob type. 
this is my code

```
$target_Path = "uploaded/";
    $target_Path = $target_Path.basename( $_FILES['image']['name'] );
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path );

    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE info SET photo='$target_Path' WHERE user_id='$id'");
```

In mysql it is showing that something has been saved but it not opening and the file is not moving into uploaded folder. i am doing this in my localhost.  Please help.

Comment: which error message  you getting and try to pass the full path  of folder

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection. Please use prepared statements and bind variables, or at *least* use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) on the variables before  you paste them into the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your move_uploaded_file with an IF statement, and throw an exception if the file fails to transfer:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_Path ) === false) {
    throw new Exception([text]);
}
```

Alternatively, to test whether the destination is writeable, you could try opening a file there and writing to it:

```
if (($fp = fopen($target_path, 'w')) === false) {
    thrown new Exception("Failed to open file $target_path for writing");
}
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
fclose($fp);
```

Chances are the problem is one of file permissions or ownership, which you'll need to fix at the command line with chmod or chown.